# Не работает медиаправило CSS

Tags: css3, html5, бэм

Устанавливаю медиаправила до 1200px, но срабатывает на 800px!!! В чем может быть причина??
Медиаправило:

```
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
.delivery {
    display: none;
}
```

}

Html

```
    <section class="delivery">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            <a href="#" class="header__logo">
                <img src="icons/gloptlogo.png" alt="logo">
            </a>
            <ul class="header__menu">
                <li class="header__item"><a href="#" class="header__link">Преимущества</a></li>
                <li class="header__item"><a href="#" class="header__link">Наша работа</a></li>
                <li class="header__item"><a href="#" class="header__link">Цены</a></li>
                <li class="header__item"><a href="#" class="header__link">Схема работы</a></li>
                <li class="header__item"><a href="#" class="header__link">Отзывы</a></li>
                <li class="header__item"><a href="#" class="header__link">Контакты</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="header__contacts">
                <div class="header__ask">Есть вопросы?</div>
                <a href="+79264230100" class="header__phone">+7 (926) 423 01 00</a>
            </div>
            <button class="button">Перезвоните мне</button>
        </div>          
        <h1 class="title-global">Global Opt - логистика полного цикла из Китая в Россию</h1>
        <h2 class="title-delivery">ДОСТАВКА ГРУЗОВ ИЗ КИТАЯ</h2>
        <h2 class="title-subtitle">В РОССИЮ И СНГ ВСЕМИ ВИДАМИ ТРАНСПОРТА</h2>
        <img src="icons/Line.png" alt="line" class="delivery__img">
        <div class="delivery__wrapper">
            <div class="delivery__item">
                <img src="icons/luggage.png" alt="luggage" class="delivery__icon">
                <div class="delivery__descr">Перевозка негабаритных и крупнотоннажных грузов</div>
            </div>
            <div class="delivery__item">
                <img src="icons/declaration.png" alt="declaration" class="delivery__icon">
                <div class="delivery__descr">Самостоятельно декларируем и проводим таможенную очистку с оптимизацией кодов и ставок</div>
            </div>
            <div class="delivery__item">
                <img src="icons/direct.png" alt="direct" class="delivery__icon">
                <div class="delivery__descr">Осуществляем прямые поставки с заводов от двери до двери</div>
            </div>
            <div class="delivery__item">
                <img src="icons/guan.png" alt="guan" class="delivery__icon">
                <div class="delivery__descr">Экспресс доставка 1-2 дня из Гуанчжоу в Москву от 25$/кг </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="button button_pay">Получить расчет</button>
    </div>
</section>
```

Код со стилями для данного блока

```
.delivery {
min-height: 680px;
padding: 23px 0 82px 0;
background: url('../../img/bgdelivery.jpg') center (center/cover) no-repeat;
&__img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10px;
}
&__wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: baseline;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
&__item {
    width: 262px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
&__descr {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.38;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

}

Comment: покажите код: как именно устанавливаете, что именно не срабатывает и т.д.

Comment: есть еще отдельные файлы стилей такие как "_title.scss", "_header.scss", "_buttton.scss", которые затрагивают секцию "_delivery.scss"
Когда добавляешь 500px к тем 1200px, тогда правило работает на нужном мне разрешении (1200px)

Comment: Сам по себе медиа-запрос работает корректно: https://jsfiddle.net/r3ckseo8/ Так что ищите, где у Вас ещё какие стили влияют на поведение секции

Comment: meta: viewport есть ?

Comment: viewport есть!!